# Sharepoint Explorer File View based on Document Library View

Tags: document-library, list-view, explorer, windows

I would like to know if it is possible to view the files in a Windows Explorer the from a document library especially when you change the view by using filters and create "views" based on metadata.

I know that I can see my files from the doc library in the Windows Explorer but that view doesn't change when I changed the view (grouping, filtering etc.) on SharePoint and then click on "Show in Windows Explorer".

Is there a way to get that feature? I am pretty sure that I am not the first one looking for that.

Best,
Stefan

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Explorer view of SharePoint does not support views defined in SharePoint. Explorer view will simply shows the folders and documents present in SharePoint and ignore any views defined in SharePoint.

Paul

Comment: Stricly speaking Windows Explorer makes a WebDav connection to the Server SharePoint is hosted on. That is why it only works in IE and not with other Browsers. So to Windows Explorer it is just another File Server, and Windows Explorer has no clue it is dealing with SharePoint. That is why SharePoint metadata is not available in Explorer either.